# Custom Xamarin Android renderer

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm doing a custom renderer in Xamarin. I haven't understood how to get it work. I've followed the following instructions:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view#Consuming_the_Custom_Control

But it's not explained how to create the android view

```
CustomRenderer.Droid.CameraPreview
```

If I create an Android view, it only a cs file and not a .xaml which I also think is strange.

I've created an empty Android view class which I try to set as my Native control from my android renderer:

```
SetNativeControl(view);
```

But it will generate a TargetInvocationException.

How is this supposed to work?

-------EDIT-------

When I run the following, nothing happends, I expected the button to be drawn in the view.

```
public class CameraRenderer : ViewRenderer<Controls.CustomControl, MainApplication.Droid.CameraPreview>
{
    private CameraPreview view;

    private Context thisContext;

    LayoutInflater inflater2;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Controls.CustomControl> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        view = new CameraPreview(thisContext);

        inflater2 = (LayoutInflater)thisContext.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
        inflater2.Inflate(Resource.Layout.layout1, view);

        SetNativeControl(view);
    }

    public CameraRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        thisContext = context;
    }
}


public class CameraPreview : ViewGroup
{
    public CameraPreview(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
    {
    }
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <Button
        android:text="Button test"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It is right that it's a .cs file. You then use your custom control like it's explained in your link: `local:CameraPreview`. Try to follow the tutorial in your link 1 by 1 and the explain what you don't understand if it won't work for you.

Comment: @DennisSchröer Thanks, I realised my mistake. However I'm still struggling with how to add controls to my CameraPreview. How should I attach e.g. a button to the view?

Comment: Then you need another custom control. For example a control named `CameraWithButton` which inherits from `RelativeLayout`. You code it just like you just coded your custom `CameraPreview`. In it's constructor, add your custom `CameraPreview` and a `Button` to `Children`. This link can help to understand how positioning in a `RelativeLayout` works: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/22902/how-to-add-a-label-to-a-relative-layout-and-center-it-horizontally

Comment: @DennisSchröer What should I use my CameraPreview to if it can't contain anything at all? It feels like a meaningless step.

Comment: @DennisSchröer What I actually want to do is to add one SciChart graph in my custom renderer.

Comment: Create the `CameraPreview` on Android, and consume it in the layout, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5779215/androidhow-to-add-a-button-in-surface-view), and use `LayoutInflater` to get the view, then call `SetNativeControl(view)`.

Answer (score 0):

> But it's not explained how to create the android view

[Here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/3575ae90cba9723f578a82198ef28d1ebff0d267/CustomRenderers/View/Droid/CameraPreview.cs) is how to create the android view `CameraPreview`. Or maybe you just want to know how to use [SurfaceView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView) to [custom camera](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/9e8439/how-to-make-a-custom-camera-ion-android/).

> If I create an Android view, it only a cs file and not a .xaml which I also think is strange.

Yes, android view is only a cs file. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37455108/xamarin-forms-system-reflection-targetinvocationexception-exception-has-been-t) is about the `TargetInvocationException` exception.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5779215/androidhow-to-add-a-button-in-surface-view) is How to add a button in surface view. From it, you can see it is using .xml file to achieve UI layout. You also can use .axml file to layout your UI, and use `LayoutInflater` to inflate your layout to a view. You can learn it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022705/why-to-use-inflater-in-listview), in the `ListView`'s adapter's `getView` method.

### Edit:

You can layout a button on it directly in your `MainPage.xaml`, like this:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <local:CameraPreview Camera="Rear"
                         x:Name="cp"
                         RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
        Property=Height,Factor=.15,Constant=0}"
    RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
        Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=1,Constant=0}"
    RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
        Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=.8,Constant=0}"/>
        <Button Text="AAAAAA"
                
                RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,
        ElementName=cp,Property=Y,Factor=1,Constant=20}"
    RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,
        ElementName=cp,Property=X,Factor=1,Constant=20}"
    RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
        Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=.5,Constant=0}"
    RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
        Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=.5,Constant=0}"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for info. Yes, I can see one example on how to design the ui from a layout. But my question is how do I "bind" the layout to my view (CameraPreview) class?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/3575ae90cba9723f578a82198ef28d1ebff0d267/CustomRenderers/View/Droid/CameraPreview.cs), `CameraPreview` is `ViewGroup`, there is a method [addView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView(android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)). Use `LayoutInflater` to inflate the layout to get the view. I hope it is clear. Or you can change the `ViewGroup` to `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: Ok, I've tried to do what you said, but it's still not working, see my code in the edited question above. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I have provided another solution in my answer, please check it.